# Code to Register msjet40.dll through msi installer class in c#

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I need to register msjet40.dll through installer class in my setup project.Please suggest code in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a setup and deployment project (i.e. as comes with Visual Studio) then you should be able to flag MDAC as a pre-requisite, which will do it for you.

Comment: How to add mdac as prerequisite as it won't come as default prerequisite.Can't we register this dll using installer.